# I am not sure how to get the view to display the way I'd like

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck, drupal-themes

I'm using a custom theme.

I have a custom content type with two fields.

1. title
2. thumbnail (created using imagecache)

Note, in the example below, URL 1 and Title 1 are the two fields for the first row in the result set.

I would like it to output something like so:

```
<span>
  <img src="URL1" />
  <span>Title 1</span>
</span>
<span>
  <img src="URL2" />
  <span>Title 2</span>
</span>
```

Basically I went a horizontal list of blocks that are flush with each other.  Each block consists of two parts, the top part is a thumbnail, the bottom part is the title.

The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure which theme override I should use.  In this case each list element consists of two fields rather than the 1 list element per field that the views module seems to expect.  Overriding fields is too low, but overriding the rows seems to be too high because I can't seem to get at the information I need.

How would you recommend I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Views, you have the ability to manipulate the display without overriding the theme.

To do this, first ensure that the image gallery module is installed.  Then, from /admin go to Site Building -> Views.  Find your view in the list and click it's edit link.  At this point if one doesn't exist, you may want to add an additional display for this specific view, or just stick with the default display.  Click on the Style type under the Basic Settings section and choose Gallery.

I haven't tried this, but it should work.

Comment: I'm using CCK imagecache to create my galleries.  The page in question isn't an image gallery, but this is the relevant parts of the design I'm struggling with at the moment.  None of the available styles match what I'm wanting.  The Views module seems to have a tendency to want to treat the fields separately (render them separately in the list), what I need to do is be able to treat all of the fields as a single entity so I can render them together.  The overridable themes don't seem to have the data I need for that though.